# Warning while upgrading MySql 5.5 to 5.6

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, mysql5.5

I'm trying to upgrade MySql from 5.5 to 5.6 in my Ubuntu machine. While running command

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.6
```

we encountered with warning like :

```
2015-07-01 18:47:58 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
```

and it is stuck for more than 2hrs. How can I proceed with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a warning, it's safe to ignore it. What you really forgot to do, is dump mysql databases in 5.5, and restore them in 5.6. `mysql_upgrade` is not an option anymore, you have to do the dump/restore sequence when upgrading major versions.

Comment: I already took database dump. Do I need to terminate the process?

Comment: I definitely would. But you can check if it's dumping or restoring something, however, I doubt it.

Comment: `mysql` command gives error `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
`  and also mysqld.sock file does not exist

Comment: Predictable. Kill it. Kill `mysqld_safe` first.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I killed mysqld_safe and all mysql process